# Redirect user after login without using LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL but from views.py

Tags: python, django

I have a django app that I use auth_views.LoginView in settings.py for my login page. I want users that when they logged in, the redirect to a custom url without changing settings.py and from views.py. this is how my code work:

```
def reserve_seat(request, movie_id, seat_id):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        print(request.user)
        new_ticket = Ticket(
            movie=Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id),
            user=request.user,
            seat=Seat.objects.get(id=seat_id)
        )
        new_ticket.save()
        return redirect('list_seats', movie_id)
    else:
        return redirect('/login')
```

I want users when they logged in , they redirects automatically to `path('<int:movie_id>/seats', list_seats, name='list_seats'),` this path

How can I handle this?

Comment: what does your code do right now for a user that is logged in?

Comment: it makes a new object from Ticket model. that`s not important now

Comment: Can you describe the desired sequence of events? it seems you want something like `@login.required` decorator, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Marat I don`t want to use @login.requred decorator. I want to login user and after that redirect user to that url path I have described in my question without form(using default djnago login app) and don`t allow to change anything in settings.py. (looking for a way to do this from views.py)

Comment: sorry, this description is still unclear.

Comment: i meant, you have `return redirect('list_seats', movie_id)` what result is that having on the client? is it not redirecting? not redirecting to the right place?

Comment: @Macattack right now when user loged in , redirects to /account/profile . I want to force user to redirect to the path I have described in my question , but don`t allow to use LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in settings.py . I have to handle this issue in views.py

Comment: My understanding of this is that `LoginView` (presumably at `/login`) will redirect the user to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` if the user is logged in/ does log in. So, is it possible your user isn't counted as being logged-in in this view? Such that you get redirected to `/login`, but then that shows you as logged-in and redirects you to `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL`? Open network tools and watch what requests and redirects happen in your browser, i think it'll help debug this. Also, are you certain you're getting into the `if request.user.is_authenticated` branch?

Comment: first you could use `print()` to see what you have in variables and which part of code is executed - it is called `"print debuging"` - and this may shows you where is the problem. Probably if you don't use `@login.requred` then you have to manually run code which will login user - and this can be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I have figured out that I have to use this code and solved my problem.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def reserve_seat(request, movie_id, seat_id):
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    print(request.user)
    new_ticket = Ticket(
        movie=Movie.objects.get(id=movie_id),
        user=request.user,
        seat=Seat.objects.get(id=seat_id)
    )
    new_ticket.save()
    return redirect('list_seats', movie_id)
```